# why does simple kafka datagen connector fail? (i.e., "state":"failed")

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

After registering the kafka data connector - with a custom schema - the status shows it is failed:
"state":"failed".

**Here is the registration**

```
$ curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/datagen01/config  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
    "kafka.topic": "topicx",
    "schema.filename": "myschema.avro",
    "schema.keyfield": "userid",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "tasks.max": "1"
}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 15:51:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 455
Server: Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)
```

**Here is the status check ("Failed")**

```
curl -s http://localhost:8083/connectors/datagen01/status
{"name":"datagen01","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"connect:8083","trace":"org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Cannot parse <null> schema\n\tat org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1595)\n\tat org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1394)\n\tat org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1365)\n\tat io.confluent.avro.random.generator.Generator$Builder.schemaStream(Generator.java:277)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenTask.start(DatagenTask.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n"}],"type":"source"}
```

*(NOTE:  the curl command is executed from the same folder that contains the myschema.avro file)*

---

**here is further background info if needed**

Dockerfile...

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.0.0
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.4.0
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'

  connect:
    image: localimage/kafka-connect-datagen:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
```

myschema.avro

```
{
    "namespace": "ksql",
    "name": "users",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "registertime", "type": {
            "type": "long",
            "arg.properties": {
                "range": {
                    "min": 1487715775521,
                    "max": 1519273364600
                }
            }
        }},
        {"name": "userid", "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "arg.properties": {
                "regex": "User_[1-9]{0,1}"
            }
        }},
        {"name": "regionid", "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "arg.properties": {
                "regex": "Region_[1-9]?"
            }
        }},
        {"name": "gender", "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "arg.properties": {
                "options": [
                    "MALE",
                    "FEMALE",
                    "OTHER"
                ]
            }
        }}
    ]
}
```

ran docker-compose...

```
    docker-compose up -d --build
```

registered datagen connector configuration

```
$ curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/datagen01/config  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
    "kafka.topic": "topicx",
    "schema.filename": "myschema.avro",
    "schema.keyfield": "userid",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "tasks.max": "1"
}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 15:51:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 455
Server: Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)
```

checked status

```
curl -s http://localhost:8083/connectors/datagen01/status
{"name":"datagen01","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"connect:8083","trace":"org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Cannot parse <null> schema\n\tat org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1595)\n\tat org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1394)\n\tat org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1365)\n\tat io.confluent.avro.random.generator.Generator$Builder.schemaStream(Generator.java:277)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenTask.start(DatagenTask.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n"}],"type":"source"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you why it failed. The schema is null.

If `schema.filename` is not in the container, then the schema would be unable to be read, regardless of where the curl command was ran

You can either copy it into the container or use a volume mount, and you'll also want to use the full file path in the config

Comment: thx - as is likely readily apparent, I'm somewhat of a docker, docker-compose and kafka newby.   --I'll give your suggestion a try and mark your answer once I verify.  appreciate your help